# php - How to keep form values after submitting to another website?

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm making a payment gateway and its submitting to itransact.com.

How to keep the values after submitting to itransact? If the values have an error to the itransact the customer back to the form and all values are gone.

Comment: You can push this values into coockies, but it's not good. Why you need to do this? I guess, you'r in wrong way. What you want to do?

Comment: I'm using this form http://itransact.com/support/demo/templates/standard-all/. Hmm that's weird this demo keep value after submitting.

Anyway my problem is.
I trying to do for example. I enter only the First Name and the Last Name then submit. Then I will get the error "saying incomplete". Then I will back to the form and complete the form. When I go back the first name and last name are gone. So I will enter again the first name and last name.

Comment: I think the from is autocomplete="off". I remove this attribute its working on chrome but not on firefox.

Comment: "Hmm that's weird this demo keep value after submitting". Because they are using "javascript:history.back()" to back to the previous page... See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to push needed values to cookies before, as form send. For example:

```
<form onsubmit="return storeValues(this);" action="" method="POST" name="userForm">
    <input type="text" value="" name="firstname">
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastname">
    <input type="submit" value="Send request">
</form>
```

Now JavaScript side:

```
<script>
  /* Set cookies to browser */
  function storeValues(form)  
  {
    setCookie("firstname", form.firstname.value);
    setCookie("lastname", form.lastname.value);
    return true;
  }

  var today = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // today + 30 days

  function setCookie(name, value)
  {
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  }
  /* --Set cookies to browser */

  function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }

  /* Loading cookie values into the form */
  if(firstname = getCookie("firstname")) document.userForm.firstname.value = firstname;
  if(lastname = getCookie("lastname")) document.userForm.lastname.value = lastname;
  /* --Loading cookie values into the form */

</script>
```

You can get more info about setting cookies using this example: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/

Comment: Sorry, missing getCookie function. Corrected this.

Comment: Yeah. I also find it here http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username.

Thanks for the tip.